# How exactly do quotes in Ruby work to form a string?

Tags: ruby

I don't quite understand how string quotes in Ruby actually work. How does wrapping something in a quote suddenly make it a string? What exactly are the quotes doing? I'm trying to understand the C or core language implementation of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What exactly are the quotes doing?

The quotes themselves do nothing. They're just markers. Here's where a string starts, here's where it ends. When your code is being parsed to be executed, the **parser** will take what's between the quotes and make a string from that content. Simple as that.

If you take a compilers course in the school, chances are that you'll have to implement your own parser and compiler/interpreter for some toy language. Likely, with strings too. It's a fun exercise! :)

BTW, in ruby you can write a string literal in many ways. Not only using quotes. This is a string too, for example

```
html = <<-HTML
  <head><title>stack overflow</title></head>
HTML
html # => "  <head><title>stack overflow</title></head>\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

In ruby the most common syntax for creating a string is using quotes like below.

```
my_msg = "Hello"
```

This is same in most other languages as well (c, java etc). AFAIK the language's parser is responsible for detecting the above syntax and continue to store `Hello` as a string in `my_msg` variable.

Ruby also has many [other syntax](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) for creating strings.